# Get authors by term id or slug

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, terms, author

This question sounds wired but I am in a situation where I need to list all author who posted in a particular term.

What I did so far, I am able to get all posts under a particular term and stored the author id into an array. But, the problem is that to create pagination over it. Does anyone know any better way to do that or any query to achieve that or any functions to solve my issue(I tried to find it out but did not get any good solution)?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom post type for authors associated with a specific tag and provide a field for author ID. Iterate over your array of authors and for each one create a new "tag author". Finally, create a WP_Query for this post type to generate a paginated output of data associated with the author ID.

Comment: So you're just using the custom post type for paging? There's going to be more work here though, e.g. clearing the CPT when someone writes a new article or changes tags on an article and then rebuilding them.. I'd think shortish-lived transients would work better for precomputed lists to page through if you want that approach, or maybe just write SQL to build the list and page through the list in the database if you can make that query efficient enough.